You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote
Olá, comunidade!
Recentemente tentei votar em uma resposta no Ask Ubuntu, mas recebi a seguinte mensagem: "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded." Sou novo aqui e gostaria de saber como posso acumular os 15 pontos de reputação necessários para começar a votar. Quais são as melhores práticas para um novato como eu começar a contribuir efetivamente e ganhar reputação na comunidade? Agradeço qualquer orientação que vocês possam me oferecer!

English only please
